# Setting date format in Yii2 REST

Tags: php, rest, date, yii2

Is there an easy way to format date that is returned with Yii2 REST API? 
For example - I have UTC dates in database and I want to format it and add `Z` at the end of the date: `2015-04-25 16:01:59Z`

Comment: Have you made any attempt at doing this? What problem are you having?

Comment: I have a dates in UTC format in my db. And in my REST service I want to display them with Z at the end of the date so clients using this service will automatically recognize that this is UTC. I just wanted to change the format on the display on the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure yii\i18n\formatter to control your global date formats for display for your locale. You can set something like this in your config file that you can access across

```
'formatter' => [
    'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
    'dateFormat' => 'php:d-M-Y',
    'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i:s',
    'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i:s',
]
```

Then you can display your date times anywhere using the formatter specified formats:

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'Today is {0, date}', $yourTimeStampAttr);
```

OR

You can easily convert any attribute format globally before saving to db. Just create a helper class like this:

```
class Setup {
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d';
    const DATETIME_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s';
    const TIME_FORMAT = 'php:H:i:s';

    public static function convert($dateStr, $type='date', $format = null) {
        if ($type === 'datetime') {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::DATETIME_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        elseif ($type === 'time') {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::TIME_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        else {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::DATE_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($dateStr, $fmt);
    }
}
```

Then anywhere else (like controller/model) you can access this function to convert any input date/time string for saving to database.

```
$model->dateAttr = Setup::convert($model->dateAttr);
$model->datetimeAttr = Setup::convert($model->datetimeAttr, 'datetime');
```

Comment: This is correct for using in View, but i was just looking for solution to do it in Yii2 REST classes, where I serve models directly from DB. The second approach seems to be fine, but then you would need to handle that in every model across whole application for read and write. Thanks anyway :)